# Different rankings in a view based on geolocation

Tags: views, 7, location

I'm currently building a site which has a ranking table.
I'd need the rankings to be different based on geolocation so what i'v done so far is building a different view for each country.
So the question is - how do i display them based on the session's location? (different home page and navigation for different countries)

Any explanation would be more than welcomed.

Edit: I'm using Zen theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Smart IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) module is help you to solve your query.

**OR**

Check [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) or [Session Cache API](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_cache) module.

Comment: Any tutorial video you might pull out of your sleeve? I'm a rather new drupalholic.

Comment: Check **README.TXT** file of these modules. I think txt file help you to understand.